# Android ViewPager delete View from Activity which is setting data for the viewpageradapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Can anyone help me out how to delete a view from another activity and confirm the changes by calling notifydatasetchanged on a Viewpager.
[This is View of My ViewPager Adapter which is getting called from a activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOWlo.png).

I want to delete a view which i'm able to achieve it from Viewpager adapter class but the problem is the delete and refresh buttons are not static with the view. I basically need the delete and refresh buttons to stick to page like footer in webpage. Right one if i swipe between views the buttons are also getting moved like how the images move.

I have seen several examples from past 2days but i could't find one which matches my criteria.

Can someone suggest me which approach to follow to achieve it.

Thanks a ton in Advance guys.

Here is my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#090909"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

    <com.example.vamshi.wheelbook.AddVehicle.ZoomableImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ViewPhoto"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/camera_black"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ImageTitle"
    android:text="Image1"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_rubbish_bin"
            android:id="@+id/Camera_Image_delete"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

  <View
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_av_replay"
            android:id="@+id/Retake_photo"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity A starting ViewpagerClass.
I want to delete a view from Activity A. How to do it?
I tired calling different methods from Activity A to delete it i was able to delete the View but notifydatasetchanged is not working that way i don't know y?

Comment: Post your activity's .xml code

Comment: What is this "other" activity? Is there only one activity or are there more? And do you want to delete a view (as in your title), or do you want to have "views stick to the page like a footer"... I don't understand. Please clarify.

Comment: it seem that you open camera and take pic and you want button to delete it

Comment: can you explain about your requirement,may be there are simple ways to achieve your goal

Comment: For example you have a Activity which take images from camera and saves it in a arraylist.. and when ever you want to view those images you click the viewimages button. When you click viewimages button a new activity starts View_images. This View_images has a viewpager in it xml which shows images when i swipe left/right. I want to delete the following images from View_images activity not from ViewImagesPagerAdapter class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, extract the buttons from viewpager in your xml files, or put the buttons as actions in your actionbar/toolbar.

EDIT: by "extract" I mean, use viewpager only to swipe between views that contain your images or whatever you do with them, while the buttons remain stationary outside of the viewpager and "docked" to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yes i tired what you suggested but i can't see the change i have called the notifydatasetchanged() method too.

Comment: How do you fill your viewpager and remove views from it?

Comment: I fill it from a activity passing following arraylist to a instance of ViewPagerAdapter class. I'm stuck at remove previous i used to delete it from ViewPagerAdapter class xml. But right now i want to achieve the following from the View_images activity so that footer stays static.

Comment: Hmm, I see now that you don't change pager adapter array. notifyDataSetChanged() won't do anything if adapter's data remains intact. If you want to preserve original array, I suggest you make a copy of it and then present the viewpager with a copy of the array on which you will actually remove views and update the adapter. Later if you want to restore original array, just replace the current pager adapter with the original one.

Comment: I have already done what you suggested @Zoran but what i want to achieve is almost done but notifydatasetchanged doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I don't think I follow you. What should notifyDataSetChanged() do for you here?

Comment: is it possible to delete a image in viewpager adapter from an activity which holds viewpager widget?

Comment: The best way I see is to remove the image from the arraylist that you pass to adapter and then calling notifyDataSetChanged(). I don't see any other way.

Comment: Hmm, it would be best if you post your code sections that show setting pager adapter data and removing data from it. There has to be something you overlooked.